# .htaccess redirect involving SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(market|other|available|areas)/ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /market/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As you can see, I currently have my htaccess setup so that any page that tries to be accessed but does not exist, will resort back to `/market/`, along with going to the original domain `example.com`, will redirect to `example.com/market/` while the other designated directories are also still available.

My simple question is, if I activate an SSL on my account, would there be anything to change with this? or does this not listen to http or https but simply the directory redirects?

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

As I kind of suspected, the original rewrite didn't pay attention to the http/https (thank you Panama Jack). Would this solution work? as it first checks to goto https, and then will send off to the /market/ directory?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(market|other|available|areas)/ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /market/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That is just a redirect. It does not take into consideration of https. You have to tell it to do that with another condition/rule. You have to create rules for everything you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @PanamaJack, I edited the question with continued possible solution, if it works like I think it would?